# .htaccess 403 404 redirect returned header SEO

Tags: .htaccess, seo, http-headers

A quick question. I want to use a php file that will deliver pages based on the url. I am using htacess to deal with the error docs but my question is to do with SEO. If I redirect a 404/403 request to pageDispacher.php that then delivers the correct page will the header be a 404/403 at any point? As this is not cool. Do I need to use a rewrite rule instead?

In which case is there is a genuine 404 page how would i return a 404 header?

www.example.com > www.example.com/en/home

www.example.com/en/ > www.example.com/en/home

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pageDispacher.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pageDispacher.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usable:

```
RewriteRule ^error error.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ error[L,QSA]
```